# OnClickListener: Why I cannot access public methods of the object in ArrayAdapter? Any workaround?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

Greetings from a greenhorn. This question is a bit long, sorry for that.
My android app loads xml to the listview, then after clicking any listview item I want to pass some information to second activity. With

```
piesneLVdata.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
```

And here is my object:

```
public class Piesen {
    private String nazov_piesne;
    private String text_piesne;
}
```

+ some get and set methods and override of toString...

I can access the first property of the object and I can use it in my second activity. I guess it is because I have overriden the method inside my object definition:

```
@Override  
public String toString() {
    return nazov_piesne;
}
```

However I am not able to access the second property of my object. Tried this:

```
piesneLVdata.getItemAtPosition(position).getTextPiesne()
```

but getTextPiesne() seems not to be reachable - then why the "toString()" is reachable? The information is there, I can access it outside of the onClickListener with this formulation:

```
zoznamPiesni.get(position).getText_piesne().toString();
```

but when I try to use it in onClickListener I get the error:

```
Error:(64, 45) error: local variable zoznamPiesni is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

But then, when I declare it final I cannot load a xml file into it. I feel officialy stucked in there. Maybe I should redesign the toString() method to contain an array of both properties of my object. Could you please point me to the correct direction? Thanks a lot in advance.

To be specific, here is my activity:
    public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView piesneLVdata;
Toolbar nadpis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    nadpis = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    nadpis.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.nadpis));
    piesneLVdata = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.piesneLVgui);

    List<Piesen> zoznamPiesni = null;

    try {
        XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
        zoznamPiesni = parser.parse(getAssets().open("piesne.xml"));

        //sort the collection piesne alphabetically a-z
        Collections.sort(zoznamPiesni, new Comparator<Piesen>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Piesen a1, Piesen a2) {

                // String implements Comparable
                return (a1.getNazov_piesne().toString()).compareTo(a2.getNazov_piesne().toString());
                }
            });
        ArrayAdapter<Piesen> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Piesen>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,zoznamPiesni);
        piesneLVdata.setAdapter(adapter);

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    piesneLVdata.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent slovaIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, SongActivity.class);
                Bundle balik = new Bundle();
                balik.putString("NAZOV", piesneLVdata.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                //balik.putString("TEXT", piesneLVdata.getItemAtPosition(position).getTextPiesne());
                // balik.putString("TEXT", zoznamPiesni.get(position).getText_piesne().toString());
                slovaIntent.putExtras(balik);
                startActivity(slovaIntent);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
piesneLVdata.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

return a `Piesen` treated as an `Object`. `Object` has toString method, so yo ucan call that method, that is overriden by the `Piesen.class`.

What you need is simply cast your object to a `Piesed` like follows:

```
((Piesen)piesneLVdata.getItemAtPosition(position)).getTextPiesne()
```

Comment: Unbelievable! That really worked! I spent several hours on researching that. My biggest Thanks to you, your answer was really helpful.